# How to change crystal report section width

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to change the width of the sections in the report. Is there a way to change the width of the section in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Crystal Reports, right click the gutter and choose 'Show Short Section Names'.  You may also choose File | Options and check 'short section names'.