# how to access gutter in crystal report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server, gutter

I need to change the width of the sections in the crystal report.
 i know,In Crystal Reports, right click the gutter and choose 'Show Short Section Names'.
but i don't know, where is gutter ?
please tell me, that where is

Comment: "width of the section", you mean the width of the page?

Comment: no, 
I need to change the width of the sections in the report.

Comment: width of a single section cant be reduced. Explain in detail which width to be reduced?

Comment: it is this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410346/how-to-change-crystal-report-section-width

Comment: Ok then, you want to reduce the size of "Section Names" ! then that would be the answer...

Comment: i set this! :-D i reduce width of section

Answer (score 0):

The gutter is literally the area which shows the section names. Alternatively you can switch between short and long section names in the crystal options window.